# adb reverse failing with Operation Not Permitted error

Tags: android, react-native, adb, kvm, strace

I am trying to run a reverse tcp link to a newly installed android emulator on linux via `adb` (trying to debug a failing call from a `react_native` build.):

```
adb -s emulator-5556 reverse --no-rebind tcp:0 tcp:8081
```

with adb version:

```
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
Version 28.0.3-5475833
```

Curiously the same command as a forward link works fine.

I am getting the result:

```
adb: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted
```

Now it looks like the emulator is what's throwing the error (adb seems to just receive this error message as a read from a process that it's communicating with, after running it via strace, and via ADB_TRACE=all).

It seems to fail after issuing a write to the adbd process with:

```
write(3, "0027reverse:forward:norebind:tcp:0;tcp:8081", 43) = 43
```

Now this is obviously a command protocol that's being sent to the emulator. (I couldn't find command number 27 with a light poking around the adb source. Any pointers?)

To try and figure out exactly what's going wrong I tried running the emulator via strace. (is it trying to write to a file that causes the permissions error? is it caused when trying to open the socket?)

Here are the `ADBTRACE=all` logs (`ADB_TRACE=all adb reverse --no-rebind tcp:0 tcp:8081`):

```
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_trace.cpp:192] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_trace.cpp:192] Version 28.0.3-5475833
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_trace.cpp:192] Installed as /home/something/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_trace.cpp:192] 
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_client.cpp:327] adb_connect: service: reverse:forward:norebind:tcp:0;tcp:8081
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_client.cpp:153] _adb_connect: host:version
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=16 30303063686f73743a76657273696f6e 000chost:version
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_client.cpp:187] _adb_connect: return fd 3
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303034 0004
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303239 0029
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_client.cpp:153] _adb_connect: reverse:forward:norebind:tcp:0;tcp:8081
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=18 30303065686f73743a74706f72743a61 000ehost:tport:a [truncated]
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_client.cpp:113] Switch transport in progress: host:tport:any
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=8
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=8 got=8 0d00000000000000 ........
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_client.cpp:127] Switch transport success
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:107] writex: fd=3 len=43 30303237726576657273653a666f7277 0027reverse:forw [truncated]
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4f4b4159 OKAY
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_client.cpp:187] _adb_connect: return fd 3
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_client.cpp:345] adb_connect: return fd 3
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 4641494c FAIL
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=4
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=4 got=4 30303264 002d
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:81] readx: fd=3 wanted=45
adb D 05-29 00:16:29 16167 16167 adb_io.cpp:97] readx: fd=3 wanted=45 got=45 63616e6e6f742062696e64206c697374 cannot bind list [truncated]
adb: error: cannot bind listener: Operation not permitted
```

When running the emulator with:

```
strace -s 10000 -f emulator -avd Pixel_2_API_Q 2>&1 | grep -C100 reverse
```

I get:

```
[pid 26748] recvfrom(79, "reverse:forward:norebind:tcp:0;tcp:8081\0", 40, 0, NULL, NULL) = 40
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN, 0)       = 0
[pid 26748] recvfrom(79, 0x7f7b49edec50, 24, 0, NULL, NULL) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN, 0)       = 0
[pid 26748] write(31, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8) = 8
[pid 26729] <... ppoll resumed>)        = 1 ([{fd=31, revents=POLLIN}], left {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9712500})
[pid 26748] write(28, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 8 <unfinished ...>
[pid 26729] futex(0x2f80ce8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] <... write resumed>)        = 8
[pid 26748] futex(0x2f80ce8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
[pid 26729] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN <unfinished ...>
[pid 26729] read(31, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 16) = 8
[pid 26729] futex(0x2f80ce8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid 26748] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26729] ppoll([{fd=31, events=POLLIN}, {fd=30, events=POLLIN}, {fd=26, events=POLLIN}, {fd=28, events=POLLIN}, {fd=52, events=POLLIN}, {fd=64, events=POLLIN}, {fd=65, events=POLLIN}, {fd=66, events=POLLIN}, {fd=67, events=POLLIN}, {fd=69, events=POLLIN}, {fd=71, events=POLLIN}, {fd=73, events=POLLIN}, {fd=75, events=POLLIN}, {fd=77, events=POLLIN}, {fd=50, events=POLLIN}, {fd=51, events=POLLIN}, {fd=34, events=POLLIN}, {fd=79, events=POLLIN}], 18, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9404000}, NULL, 8 <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN <unfinished ...>
[pid 26729] <... ppoll resumed>)        = 1 ([{fd=28, revents=POLLIN}], left {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9399241})
[pid 26748] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26729] read(31,  <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] futex(0x2f80ce8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 26729] <... read resumed>0x7f7bb75925a0, 16) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
[pid 26729] read(28, "\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 512) = 8
[pid 26729] futex(0x2f80ce8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 26729] <... futex resumed>)        = 1
[pid 26729] ppoll([{fd=31, events=POLLIN}, {fd=30, events=POLLIN}, {fd=26, events=POLLIN}, {fd=28, events=POLLIN}, {fd=52, events=POLLIN}, {fd=64, events=POLLIN}, {fd=65, events=POLLIN}, {fd=66, events=POLLIN}, {fd=67, events=POLLIN}, {fd=69, events=POLLIN}, {fd=71, events=POLLIN}, {fd=73, events=POLLIN}, {fd=75, events=POLLIN}, {fd=77, events=POLLIN}, {fd=50, events=POLLIN}, {fd=51, events=POLLIN}, {fd=34, events=POLLIN}, {fd=79, events=POLLIN}], 18, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=9246000}, NULL, 8 <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] futex(0x2f80ce8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN, 0)       = 0
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN <unfinished ...>
[pid 26747] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26747] ioctl(53, KVM_RUN <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN, 0)       = 0
[pid 26747] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN <unfinished ...>
[pid 26747] sendto(79, "OKAY\256\2\0\0X\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\260\264\276\246", 24, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26747] <... sendto resumed>)       = 24
[pid 26747] ioctl(53, KVM_RUN <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN <unfinished ...>
[pid 26747] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26748] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26747] sendto(79, "WRTE\256\2\0\0X\1\0\0005\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\250\255\253\272", 24, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] futex(0x2f80ce8, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 2, NULL <unfinished ...>
[pid 26747] <... sendto resumed>)       = 24
[pid 26747] futex(0x2f80ce8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 26747] <... futex resumed>)        = 1
[pid 26748] futex(0x2f80ce8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
[pid 26747] ioctl(53, KVM_RUN <unfinished ...>
[pid 26748] <... futex resumed>)        = 0
[pid 26748] ioctl(54, KVM_RUN <unfinished ...>
[pid 26747] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26748] <... ioctl resumed>, 0)     = 0
[pid 26747] sendto(79, "FAIL002dcannot bind listener: Operation not permitted", 53, MSG_NOSIGNAL, NULL, 0 <unfinished ...>
```

Now this doesn't make much sense unless it is an error inside the kvm_run stuff (I'm not *super* familiar with kvm.)

So I'm assuming this is some simple permissions problem, but my messing around doesn't allow me to figure out *where* the permissions problem is.

Is anyone able to help shed light on how to deal with this error for adb? are there any strace/kvm wizards who can point out how I can find out where this permissions error is?

Comment: I'm confused, so the logcat wasn't useful enough to identify the issue? It may also help to describe what the app is trying to do when it fails.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I included the ADBTRACE logs. The error doesn't appear to be in the application, it's before I start the application I'm just trying to open a reverse socket from the device to my machine. I think it should be the equivalent of `ssh -L 8081:android_emulator:8081` but it appears to be failing.

Comment: You can capture the output `adb logcat` from just before your app is started through whatever happens (crash?). Use a fresh newly created emulator or a device (in case its a emulator issue). If the app installs correctly, there has to be some Android logging stack trace which isn't what you are showing.

Comment: @MorrisonChang there is a bug before starting the application. I am encountering a bug running `adb -s emulator-5556 reverse --no-rebind tcp:0 tcp:8081` without an application being started.

Answer (score 2):

Try to restart the adbd daemon with root permissions:

```
adb kill-server; adb root
```

Comment: Running `adb root` gives me `adbd cannot run as root in production builds` as an error.

Comment: Try `adb shell "su"` instead

Comment: `/system/bin/sh: su: inaccessible or not found` this is just on a stock android 9 pixel 2 emulator.